# If a wire undergoes longitudinal stress and there is significant change in area. Is the stress Force/old area or Force/ new area?

Tags: forces, solid-state-physics, stress-strain

Supposed a wire undergoes longitudinal stress and its diameter changes non negligibly, how is the stress calculated, is it Force/old area or Force/new area. Please comment if my question is inadequate.

Comment: You will have to calculate the $\frac{force}{old area}$ to get the average amount of stress, however stress in this case will be varying with the decrease in the cross-section area (at some fixed point please note this because this will not be true throughout the whole rod).

Comment: And You can't merely ask that what should be the stress. Instead of this, you should ask that at some instant what should be the stress at that moment on any specific cross-section area such as after 2 seconds, 3 seconds etc. because here the area seems to be the function of time and also seems to be decreasing at some rate so stress should increase with time as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both ratios are used. Where it is necessary to distinguish between them, force/original cross-sectional area is called "engineering stress" or "apparent stress", whereas force/new cross-sectional area is called "true stress". See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93strain_curve) for more details.

Comment: please read the comment above at the OP's post please tell me is it true or something is wrong, So that I can improve my answer.